# flex display for label tag taking space at the bottom for bigger text

Tags: html, css

i have an html label field
`<label className='flexRow'>Premium Economy</label>`
the flexRow class is

```
.flexRow{
display:flex;
}
```

but because of the text length being too big i am not able to get it adjust horizontally what can be done to fit the text in the line without taking space at the bottom in html

Comment: Can't really tell what you are talking about here; please present a proper [mre] of your issue, instead of just snippets that lack context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure that text within the `<label>` fits in a single line, without consuming space at bottom, you need to apply the `overflow` and `text-overflow` properties in CSS.

Furthermore, you can try the `white-space` property to control how the text wraps within the element.

CSS:

```
.flexRow {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```